# Update the id with some field id in another table

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008-r2

How to Update all employee `departmentID` who belongs to `department` code `500` to department code `503`

**tHREmployee

```
> EmployeeId #.......Employeee.........DepartmentID
...101...............Ajith.............101
...102...............Arathy ...........Null
...103...............Arurna............102
...104...............Ambily............101
...105...............Anjaly............Null
...106...............Babitha...........103
```

**tHRDepartment

```
 DepartmentID #.............Code
 101........................500
 102........................501
 103........................502
 105........................503
 ..
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
DECLARE @CodeFrom AS INT
DECLARE @CodeTo AS INT

SET    @CodeFrom = 500 
SET    @CodeTo= 503

UPDATE tHREmployee
SET    DepartmentID = (
                          SELECT DepartmentID 
                          FROM   tHRDepartment 
                          WHERE  Code = @CodeTo
                      )
FROM   tHREmployee E
       JOIN tHRDepartment D
       ON E.DepartmentID  = D.DepartmentID 
WHERE  D.Code = @CodeFrom
```

Answer (score 0):

What about this:

```
 Declare @NewDepID int
 Select   @NewDepID = DepartmentID from Departments Where DepartmentCode = 503

 update tHREmployee 
 Set DepartmentID = @NewDepID
 Where DepartmentID in (Select DepartmentID from Departments Where DepartmentCode = 500)
```

Comment: but departmentID is unkwon not able to point out specific value from DepartmentID.

Answer (score 0):

Update tHREmployee SET DepartmentID = 105 WHERE DepartmentID = 101;